# Ionic 2 page navigation not working

Tags: ionic2

Trying to navigate from the starting page (i'm using a side menu rather than tabs).
The navigation seems to work, but only after pressing the button twice (the old pages does not leave the DOM, but the new pages constructor fires, and replaces the header to the page. I can then press the navigate button again, which re-runs it's page logic and renders the rest of the page. I've attached some screenshots:

This is the main login:
[image: This is the main login:]

After pressing the button to login, the next pages logic runs, and the header changes. But the old page doesn't leave.
[image]

I can press login again, the next pages logic runs again then it renders the page.
[image]

Here's the code:

```
login(){
    this.refToProgram.loggedIn = true;

    this.nav.push(NearmePage).then(
      response => {
        console.log('Response ' + response);
      },
      error => {
        console.log('Error: ' + error);
      }
    ).catch(exception => {
      console.log('Exception ' + exception);
    });
}
```

The result of this is: 'Response true'
Which means ionic thinks the navigation was successful, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

try to navigate with `[navPush]= "nearmePage";` Inside the login button

Inside your controller

Insert the nearmePage class and the inside your LoginPage class

declare `nearmePage = "NearmePage"` so that will take to the respected page form login page